# When performing a collections operation, is it possible to modify the underlying collection?

Tags: kotlin, collections

For example, I have the following code to recursively copy a directory's contents.

```kotlin
    private fun copyContentDirectory(directory : File): List<File> {
        val files = directory.listFiles().toList()
        val filesToTransform = mutableListOf<File>()

        // Add each file + directory. Then, recursively add the files in each directory.
        files
                .onEach  { filesToTransform += it }
                .filter  { it.isDirectory }
                .forEach { filesToTransform += copyContentDirectory(it) }

        return filesToTransform
    }
```

Is it possible to have something like the following?  If not, why not?

```kotlin
    private fun copyContentDirectory(directory : File): List<File> {
        return directory.listFiles().toList()
                .filter  { it.isDirectory }
                .onEach  { <thisList> += copyContentDirectory(it) }
    }
```

Where `thisList` is some symbol that allows me to reference the underlying list.  Does such a thing exist?

Comment: What is "thisList` in your 2nd snippet?

Comment: @Francesc, edited.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not clear on what you want to do. Your <thislist> is actually a File, not a list. What is your intention?

Comment: `val files = File(path).walk().toList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, your intentions aren't very clear.

Looking at the second example, the obvious answer would seem to be to replace this line:

```
.onEach { <thisList> += copyContentDirectory(it) }
```

with one using [`flatMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/flat-map.html), e.g.:

```
.flatMap{ copyContentDirectory(it) }
```

That collects together the results from all the recursive calls, and returns them as a single list — which I think is what you want.

However, that just reveals deeper problems:

- Despite the name, the method isn't actually copying anything, just collecting together a list.
- The list will always be empty — it recurses over directories, but never returns any files, so will only every be combining empty lists.

Here's a version which addresses the second problem.  I've also renamed it, recast it as an extension function, and used [`partition()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/partition.html) to avoid filtering twice.  (The first result is those files matching the predicate, i.e. directories, over which it recurses; the second is files not matching, i.e. non-directories, which it includes directly.)  And because [`listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) can return null in some circumstances, it has to handle that too.

```
private fun File.listContents(): List<File>
    = listFiles()
        ?.partition{ it.isDirectory }
        ?.let{ it.first.flatMap{ it.listContents() } + it.second }
        ?: listOf()
```

(That doesn't address the copying, but the question doesn't indicate how you plan to approach that.)

Comment: Thanks! flatMap is what I needed!